# Show that every open disc in a plane is an open set in euclidean topology

Tags: general-topology

**Problem**
Prove that disc {$x,y: x^2 +y^2 < 1$} is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and then that every open disc in the plane is an open set.

**Steps involved**

(i) Let $a,b$ be any point in the disc

$D$ = {$x,y: x^2 +y^2 < 1$}.Put 
$r=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$ .Let $R_{(a,b)}$ be the open rectangle with vertices at the points $a± \frac{1−r}{8} , b± \frac{1−r}{8}$. Verify that $R_(a,b)⊂ D$.

(ii) Using (i) show that $D= \cup R_{(a,b)}$. $a,b ∈D$

(iii) Deduce from (ii) that D is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

(iv) Show that every disc

{$(x,y): (x−a)^2 +(y −b)^2 < c^2, a,b,c ∈ \mathbb{R}$}

**Attempt**

To prove step 1, i am trying to show that 
$(a+\frac{1-r}{8})^2 + (b+\frac{1-r}{8})^2 \leq 1$ but i couldn't prove it .

$(a+\frac{1-r}{8})^2 + (b+\frac{1-r}{8})^2 \leq 
(a+\frac{1}{8})^2 + (b+\frac{1}{8})^2 .$. 
How to proceed.

**NB - I am more comfortable using neighborhood around (x,y) and proving it.**

Comment: a) I am not sure what $a$ and $b$ are. b) How do you define an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: (a,b) is a point inside the disk. Standard topology .

Comment: So your basis is the set of all open rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^2$, I presume. But I think that this idea of the specific constants you have here is fishy. I would take an epsilon, the choice of which follows from the Euclidean distance, and carry on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topology on the plane is given by the metric $d$ presumably ($d$ is the Euclidean square root metric, $d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) = \sqrt{((x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2-y_2)^2}$).

The open unit ball $B$ is just $B_d((0,0),1)$, the $d$-ball around the origin $0$ with radius $1$ (as $x^2 + y^2 < 1$ iff $d((x,y),(0,0)) < 1$). And in a metric space any 
open ball is open in the metric topology:

Let $(x,y) \in B$. Then $d((x,y), (0,0)) < 1$ so define $r = 1 - d((x,y), (0,0)) > 0$. Then $B_d((x,y), r) \subseteq B$ because if $(u,v) \in B_d((x,y), r)$ then 
by the triangle inequality:

$$d((u,v),(0,0)) \le d((u,v), (x,y)) + d((x,y),(0,0)) < r + d((x,y), (0,0)) = 1$$

so that $(u,v) \in B$.

This argument works in any metric space: all open balls are indeed open (i.e. in the metric topology), hence the name "open" ball, of course.